# Styling “input file” - works great, but there is a little annoying problem

Tags: css, file-io, firefox3.6

I'm using **Firefox 3.6.6**.

I styled my "input file" that looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code: (live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ZDzbq/1/))

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="customButton">
        <img src="http://i28.tinypic.com/2nv5lww.png" />
        <span>Choose Files</span>
    </div>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" size="1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 339px;
    height: 66px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-70deg, 
                                     rgba(1, 36, 68, 0.9), 
                                     rgba(10, 103, 196, 0.9));
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -20px -20px 20px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 
                     inset 20px 20px 20px -20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
#fileInput {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
}
img {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 12px;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 95px;
    top: 7px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

The only problem is that when the mouse is over this custom button, the cursor changes between `text` and `default` because of the underlying "input file" (which is not visible).

Does anyone has an idea how could I set the cursor to `pointer`, for example, when the mouse hovers the button ?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Have you tried putting `cursor: pointer;` in your CSS?

Comment: Did you try `cursor: pointer;` on the `<div>` that wraps it?

Comment: Yes, I tried to put `cursor: pointer;` on everything I could thing of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="fileInput" style="display: none;" type="file" size="1" />
```

it seems to be working with you hide it and put cursor:pointer to wrapper

Comment: It's not good enough because then the "Choose File" dialog box will not be opened once you click the button.